# WSL or Windows: from where mount source code of nodejs app

Tags: node.js, docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop, vscode-devcontainer

I have a Windows 11 setup with WSL 2.
And I need to run node.js app inside docker container for development(using Vs code Dev containers).

My wsl distro(Ubuntu) also has access to `docker` executable(docker desktop is shared between wsl and windows as I understand).

So I have two options:

1: store app source files on my local windows machine, start `node` docker container and mount my directory to this container.

2: store app source files in wsl(Ubuntu), start `node` docker container from wsl(Ubuntu) and mount my directory from wsl to docker container.

What is the difference and which option is better especially when using Vs code Dev containers.

Option 2 seems for me as 2 layers of abstraction(windows -> WSL(Ubuntu) -> nodejs docker container) where option 1 is just (Windows -> nodejs docker container)

But I also had read that when you work on a Linux specific project - better to develop it and store in WSL, and vice versa for Windows specific projects. But in my case I anyway run additional nodejs docker container on top, so not sure if it applies here and does it make sense to store files in wsl if I need additional docker container anyway...???

Comment: This question is fairly opinion-based and likely to be closed. However to be helpful I can offer my opinion. I would choose option 2. I would not be worrying about "windows specific projects" (or linux, etc) for anything in node.js and rather just develop for what works in your docker container.

Comment: I'd probably just [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download) and be done with it, without trying to involve Docker at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze the point is to make usable dev environment for project which requires multiple dependencies /services described in docker compose. Installing everything globally will be a mess with hard way to get new person to the team and setup project. That is why docker especially docker compose helps. Also keeping the same versions of packages and make dev environment close to production. And simply better DX using `docker compose up` instead of hundreds of lines in command line...

Comment: Docker is great for running dependencies like databases, but it's problematic to have your application interpreter on the other side of an isolation boundary from your source code.  You can use a host Node to run host code with containerized dependencies, for example.

Comment: If you have to install tons of dependencies/multiple programming languages/compilers/proxies it is easier to do it in some container, we don't wanna install lot of stuff locally on our laptops, so when it is in container you can remove everything with it at any time. Vs code Dev containers provide quite good support for it(same as local dev) I just wanna figure out what is the best way to use it.